# Is it possible to send desktop notifications to all logged in users in Active Directory?

Tags: c#, windows, notifications, active-directory

I would like to know if it's possible to create a C# program that sends real time custom desktop notifications to all logged in users in Active Directory.

If so, may I have some guidance?

Or is there already a built-in functionality in Windows Server to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: If you mean built-in functionality then not that I know of. The closest you will get might be [this](https://www.lifewire.com/msg-command-2618093)

Comment: [msg](https://www.winsentmessenger.com/msg/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's possible.

As mentioned in the comments, the only built-in option that's close to what you want is [msg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msg). But it probably won't work the way you want. You can only target one computer with it, so if you want to target *every* logged on user, then you need to repeat that command for every computer in your environment.

You can try it yourself with this command:

```
msg * "hello"
```

That will send the message "hello" to every person logged on to the computer that you run it on (likely only you). Use the `/server:` option to send the message to another computer.

If you want to make your own application, then it will need to be a client/server type application. The client application will:

- Be pushed out to every computer in your environment
- Automatically run when a user logs in (under their credentials, so you can pop up an interactive window - that's more difficult to do if you run it as a Windows service)
- Either poll the server to see if a new message is available, or keep a connection open with the server so the server can push a message (depending on the size of your organization, you might run into problems keeping that many connections open)

The server application will:

- Have a UI, which allows you to add messages
- Keep a database of the messages
- Keep track of which computers have received and displayed the message
- Probably other things